# Schur complement, Congruence Transformation and Positive Semi definiteness

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, schur-complement

The Schur Complement of a block matrix $A$ in $X$ where
$$
X = \begin{bmatrix}
      A & B \\
      B^T& C
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
is defined as $S = C-B^TA^{-1}B$ whenever $A$ is non-singular. For one, I know that if $A = 0$, then for $X$ to be positive semidefinite, $B = 0$ and $C \succeq 0$ must hold true. (Here $\succeq$ denotes positive semi-definiteness). But I don't know how to prove it here (even for a $2 \times 2$ block matrix).

Here is my attempt at a proof (when $A = 0$)

Consider $P = \begin{bmatrix} I & 0 \\ -B^T & I\end{bmatrix}$. Then, since $X$ is congruent to $Y = PXP^T$, so $X \succeq 0 \Leftrightarrow Y \succeq 0$ because $P$ is non-singular. Expanding $Y$ we get $Y = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & C-B^TB \end{bmatrix}$. Now, for $Y$ to be PSD, all we need is $C-B^TB \succeq 0$.

I don't see how that puts a restriction on $C$ and $B$ individually.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you are asking. If you consider $\begin{bmatrix} x^T & y^T \end{bmatrix} X \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = 2x^TBy + y^TC y$ it is straightforward to show that if $By \neq 0$ then you can choose $x$ such that the formula is negative. Hence $B=0$. Then it follows that $C \ge 0$.

Comment: That makes no sense.

Comment: @copper.hat why? Can you prove this along the line I started? That would be much helpful for me

Comment: Clarity what you are asking. Are you trying to show that if $X \ge 0$ then $B=0$ and $C \ge 0$? If so, I have answered this. If not, please elaborate.

Comment: @copper.hat Yes I am trying to prove that if $X \succeq 0$ then $B = 0$ and $C \succeq 0$ but I am also trying to look for a proof that is along the lines I have written in my question.

Comment: I have no idea how you ended up with $Y$ above, it does not look like $PXP^T$ to me.